# org.elasticsearch.action.NoShardAvailableActionException: null

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, xpack

Before x-pack plugin installed，My ElasticSearch is health；

After x-pack plugin installed，some security error occured，

so,I'm setting

```
xpack.security.enabled: false
```

in my elasticsearch.yml and kibana.yml, and then restarting elasticsearch successed.

But sometime the following errors occured.

```
deMacBook-Pro:bin yyq$ ./elasticsearch
[2017-02-16T11:44:15,349][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [yml-es-node-1] initializing ...
[2017-02-16T11:44:15,542][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [yml-es-node-1] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/ (/dev/disk1)]], net usable_space [9.1gb], net total_space [232.6gb], spins? [unknown], types [hfs]
[2017-02-16T11:44:15,543][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [yml-es-node-1] heap size [1.9gb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
[2017-02-16T11:44:15,665][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [yml-es-node-1] node name [yml-es-node-1], node ID [hqVAcDOdRu-LXuAgUEX9oQ]
[2017-02-16T11:44:15,670][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [yml-es-node-1] version[5.2.0], pid[18949], build[24e05b9/2017-01-24T19:52:35.800Z], OS[Mac OS X/10.11.6/x86_64], JVM[Oracle Corporation/Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM/1.8.0_25/25.25-b02]
[2017-02-16T11:44:21,007][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [yml-es-node-1] loaded module [aggs-matrix-stats]
[2017-02-16T11:44:21,008][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [yml-es-node-1] loaded module [ingest-common]
[2017-02-16T11:44:21,008][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [yml-es-node-1] loaded module [lang-expression]
[2017-02-16T11:44:21,008][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [yml-es-node-1] loaded module [lang-groovy]
[2017-02-16T11:44:21,008][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [yml-es-node-1] loaded module [lang-mustache]
[2017-02-16T11:44:21,008][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [yml-es-node-1] loaded module [lang-painless]
[2017-02-16T11:44:21,008][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [yml-es-node-1] loaded module [percolator]
[2017-02-16T11:44:21,009][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [yml-es-node-1] loaded module [reindex]
[2017-02-16T11:44:21,009][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [yml-es-node-1] loaded module [transport-netty3]
[2017-02-16T11:44:21,009][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [yml-es-node-1] loaded module [transport-netty4]
[2017-02-16T11:44:21,010][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [yml-es-node-1] loaded plugin [x-pack]
[2017-02-16T11:44:28,308][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [yml-es-node-1] initialized
[2017-02-16T11:44:28,309][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [yml-es-node-1] starting ...
[2017-02-16T11:44:28,688][INFO ][o.e.t.TransportService   ] [yml-es-node-1] publish_address {127.0.0.1:9301}, bound_addresses {[fe80::1]:9301}, {[::1]:9301}, {127.0.0.1:9301}
[2017-02-16T11:44:31,856][INFO ][o.e.c.s.ClusterService   ] [yml-es-node-1] detected_master {yml-es-node-2}{5flQkMYSR-ab1dgNA6coog}{fdX0iBHhSzG3Mrri_5ooNA}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}, added {{yml-es-node-2}{5flQkMYSR-ab1dgNA6coog}{fdX0iBHhSzG3Mrri_5ooNA}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300},}, reason: zen-disco-receive(from master [master {yml-es-node-2}{5flQkMYSR-ab1dgNA6coog}{fdX0iBHhSzG3Mrri_5ooNA}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300} committed version [1]])
[2017-02-16T11:44:31,881][INFO ][o.e.h.HttpServer         ] [yml-es-node-1] publish_address {127.0.0.1:9200}, bound_addresses {[fe80::1]:9200}, {[::1]:9200}, {127.0.0.1:9200}
[2017-02-16T11:44:31,882][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [yml-es-node-1] started
[2017-02-16T11:44:32,853][INFO ][o.e.l.LicenseService     ] [yml-es-node-1] license [854880ad-c73b-4bdc-8813-918c125d442b] mode [trial] - valid
[2017-02-16T11:47:32,980][INFO ][o.e.m.j.JvmGcMonitorService] [yml-es-node-1] [gc][184] overhead, spent [261ms] collecting in the last [1s]
[2017-02-16T11:48:37,797][DEBUG][o.e.a.s.TransportSearchAction] [yml-es-node-1] All shards failed for phase: [query]
org.elasticsearch.action.NoShardAvailableActionException: null
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.AbstractSearchAsyncAction.start(AbstractSearchAsyncAction.java:115) [elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.TransportSearchAction.doExecute(TransportSearchAction.java:154) [elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.TransportSearchAction.doExecute(TransportSearchAction.java:53) [elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction$RequestFilterChain.proceed(TransportAction.java:173) [elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction.execute(TransportAction.java:145) [elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction.execute(TransportAction.java:87) [elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.TransportMultiSearchAction.executeSearch(TransportMultiSearchAction.java:113) [elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.TransportMultiSearchAction.doExecute(TransportMultiSearchAction.java:88) [elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.TransportMultiSearchAction.doExecute(TransportMultiSearchAction.java:41) [elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction.doExecute(TransportAction.java:149) [elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction$RequestFilterChain.proceed(TransportAction.java:173) [elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction.execute(TransportAction.java:145) [elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction.execute(TransportAction.java:87) [elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.node.NodeClient.executeLocally(NodeClient.java:75) [elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.node.NodeClient.doExecute(NodeClient.java:64) [elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.execute(AbstractClient.java:403) [elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.multiSearch(AbstractClient.java:560) [elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.rest.action.search.RestMultiSearchAction.lambda$prepareRequest$0(RestMultiSearchAction.java:78) [elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.rest.action.search.RestMultiSearchAction$$Lambda$1847/1830071645.accept(Unknown Source) [elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.rest.BaseRestHandler.handleRequest(BaseRestHandler.java:82) [elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.rest.RestController.dispatchRequest(RestController.java:162) [elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.http.HttpServer.dispatchRequest(HttpServer.java:115) [elasticsearch-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.http.netty4.Netty4HttpServerTransport.dispatchRequest(Netty4HttpServerTransport.java:515) [transport-netty4-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.http.netty4.Netty4HttpRequestHandler.channelRead0(Netty4HttpRequestHandler.java:70) [transport-netty4-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105) [netty-transport-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363) [netty-transport-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:349) [netty-transport-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:341) [netty-transport-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
    at org.elasticsearch.http.netty4.pipelining.HttpPipeliningHandler.channelRead(HttpPipeliningHandler.java:66) [transport-netty4-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363) [netty-transport-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:349) [netty-transport-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:341) [netty-transport-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
    at org.elasticsearch.http.netty4.cors.Netty4CorsHandler.channelRead(Netty4CorsHandler.java:76) [transport-netty4-5.2.0.jar:5.2.0]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363) [netty-transport-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:349) [netty-transport-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:341) [netty-transport-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102) [netty-codec-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageCodec.channelRead(MessageToMessageCodec.java:111) [netty-codec-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363) [netty-transport-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:349) [netty-transport-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:341) [netty-transport-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102) [netty-codec-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363) [netty-transport-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:349) [netty-transport-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:341) [netty-transport-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102) [netty-codec-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363) [netty-transport-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:349) [netty-transport-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:341) [netty-transport-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:293) [netty-codec-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:267) [netty-codec-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363) [netty-transport-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:349) [netty-transport-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:341) [netty-transport-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelRead(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:86) [netty-transport-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363) [netty-transport-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:349) [netty-transport-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:341) [netty-transport-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1334) [netty-transport-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363) [netty-transport-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:349) [netty-transport-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:926) [netty-transport-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:129) [netty-transport-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:642) [netty-transport-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysPlain(NioEventLoop.java:527) [netty-transport-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:481) [netty-transport-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:441) [netty-transport-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858) [netty-common-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_25]
```

anyone can help me?

#### Delete data directory and restarting elasticsearch,kibana,elasticsearch-head,show some error messages.

```
deMacBook-Pro:bin yyq$ ./elasticsearch
[2017-02-17T10:56:37,391][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [yml-es-node-1] initializing ...
[2017-02-17T10:56:37,875][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [yml-es-node-1] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/ (/dev/disk1)]], net usable_space [4.6gb], net total_space [232.6gb], spins? [unknown], types [hfs]
[2017-02-17T10:56:37,875][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [yml-es-node-1] heap size [1.9gb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
[2017-02-17T10:56:37,879][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [yml-es-node-1] node name [yml-es-node-1], node ID [nIE4QoyTQ9yh8Nz_vidq5A]
[2017-02-17T10:56:37,888][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [yml-es-node-1] version[5.2.0], pid[45986], build[24e05b9/2017-01-24T19:52:35.800Z], OS[Mac OS X/10.11.6/x86_64], JVM[Oracle Corporation/Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM/1.8.0_25/25.25-b02]
[2017-02-17T10:56:42,151][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [yml-es-node-1] loaded module [aggs-matrix-stats]
[2017-02-17T10:56:42,160][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [yml-es-node-1] loaded module [ingest-common]
[2017-02-17T10:56:42,161][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [yml-es-node-1] loaded module [lang-expression]
[2017-02-17T10:56:42,161][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [yml-es-node-1] loaded module [lang-groovy]
[2017-02-17T10:56:42,162][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [yml-es-node-1] loaded module [lang-mustache]
[2017-02-17T10:56:42,162][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [yml-es-node-1] loaded module [lang-painless]
[2017-02-17T10:56:42,162][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [yml-es-node-1] loaded module [percolator]
[2017-02-17T10:56:42,164][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [yml-es-node-1] loaded module [reindex]
[2017-02-17T10:56:42,165][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [yml-es-node-1] loaded module [transport-netty3]
[2017-02-17T10:56:42,166][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [yml-es-node-1] loaded module [transport-netty4]
[2017-02-17T10:56:42,167][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [yml-es-node-1] loaded plugin [x-pack]
[2017-02-17T10:56:49,011][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [yml-es-node-1] initialized
[2017-02-17T10:56:49,012][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [yml-es-node-1] starting ...
[2017-02-17T10:56:49,531][INFO ][o.e.t.TransportService   ] [yml-es-node-1] publish_address {127.0.0.1:9300}, bound_addresses {[fe80::1]:9300}, {[::1]:9300}, {127.0.0.1:9300}
[2017-02-17T10:56:55,760][INFO ][o.e.c.s.ClusterService   ] [yml-es-node-1] detected_master {yml-es-node-2}{0got1rmqQX-HcD9Wp3uEUA}{2C-_m1pkQv-YKzAPs3v5JA}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9301}, added {{yml-es-node-2}{0got1rmqQX-HcD9Wp3uEUA}{2C-_m1pkQv-YKzAPs3v5JA}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9301},}, reason: zen-disco-receive(from master [master {yml-es-node-2}{0got1rmqQX-HcD9Wp3uEUA}{2C-_m1pkQv-YKzAPs3v5JA}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9301} committed version [1]])
[2017-02-17T10:56:55,797][INFO ][o.e.h.HttpServer         ] [yml-es-node-1] publish_address {127.0.0.1:9200}, bound_addresses {[fe80::1]:9200}, {[::1]:9200}, {127.0.0.1:9200}
[2017-02-17T10:56:55,797][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [yml-es-node-1] started
[2017-02-17T10:56:56,701][INFO ][o.e.l.LicenseService     ] [yml-es-node-1] license [1e32f145-313f-4129-b3f2-666bbf279cc5] mode [trial] - valid

------------------------------------------
deMacBook-Pro:bin yyq$ ./kibana
  log   [02:57:14.219] [info][status][plugin:kibana@5.2.0] Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready
  log   [02:57:14.302] [info][status][plugin:elasticsearch@5.2.0] Status changed from uninitialized to yellow - Waiting for Elasticsearch
  log   [02:57:14.327] [info][status][plugin:xpack_main@5.2.0] Status changed from uninitialized to yellow - Waiting for Elasticsearch
  log   [02:57:14.545] [info][status][plugin:graph@5.2.0] Status changed from uninitialized to yellow - Waiting for Elasticsearch
  log   [02:57:14.554] [warning][reporting] Generating a random key for xpack.reporting.encryptionKey. To prevent pending reports from failing on restart, please set xpack.reporting.encryptionKey in kibana.yml
  log   [02:57:14.558] [info][status][plugin:reporting@5.2.0] Status changed from uninitialized to yellow - Waiting for Elasticsearch
  log   [02:57:14.594] [info][status][plugin:searchprofiler@5.2.0] Status changed from uninitialized to yellow - Waiting for Elasticsearch
  log   [02:57:14.603] [info][status][plugin:tilemap@5.2.0] Status changed from uninitialized to yellow - Waiting for Elasticsearch
  log   [02:57:14.613] [info][status][plugin:console@5.2.0] Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready
  log   [02:57:14.853] [info][status][plugin:timelion@5.2.0] Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready
  log   [02:57:14.859] [info][listening] Server running at http://localhost:5601
  log   [02:57:14.860] [info][status][ui settings] Status changed from uninitialized to yellow - Elasticsearch plugin is yellow
  log   [02:57:19.563] [info][status][plugin:xpack_main@5.2.0] Status changed from yellow to yellow - No existing Kibana index found
  log   [02:57:19.565] [info][status][plugin:graph@5.2.0] Status changed from yellow to yellow - No existing Kibana index found
  log   [02:57:19.565] [info][status][plugin:reporting@5.2.0] Status changed from yellow to yellow - No existing Kibana index found
  log   [02:57:19.567] [info][status][plugin:searchprofiler@5.2.0] Status changed from yellow to yellow - No existing Kibana index found
  log   [02:57:19.568] [info][status][plugin:tilemap@5.2.0] Status changed from yellow to yellow - No existing Kibana index found
  log   [02:57:19.568] [info][status][plugin:elasticsearch@5.2.0] Status changed from yellow to yellow - No existing Kibana index found
  log   [02:57:49.583] [error][status][plugin:xpack_main@5.2.0] Status changed from yellow to red - Unable to create Kibana index ".kibana"
  log   [02:57:49.584] [error][status][plugin:graph@5.2.0] Status changed from yellow to red - Unable to create Kibana index ".kibana"
  log   [02:57:49.584] [error][status][plugin:reporting@5.2.0] Status changed from yellow to red - Unable to create Kibana index ".kibana"
  log   [02:57:49.587] [error][status][plugin:searchprofiler@5.2.0] Status changed from yellow to red - Unable to create Kibana index ".kibana"
  log   [02:57:49.590] [error][status][plugin:tilemap@5.2.0] Status changed from yellow to red - Unable to create Kibana index ".kibana"
  log   [02:57:49.593] [error][status][plugin:elasticsearch@5.2.0] Status changed from yellow to red - Unable to create Kibana index ".kibana"
  log   [02:57:49.594] [error][status][ui settings] Status changed from yellow to red - Elasticsearch plugin is red
  log   [02:57:52.120] [error][status][plugin:xpack_main@5.2.0] Status changed from red to red - Elasticsearch is still initializing the kibana index.
  log   [02:57:52.120] [error][status][plugin:graph@5.2.0] Status changed from red to red - Elasticsearch is still initializing the kibana index.
  log   [02:57:52.121] [error][status][plugin:reporting@5.2.0] Status changed from red to red - Elasticsearch is still initializing the kibana index.
  log   [02:57:52.122] [error][status][plugin:searchprofiler@5.2.0] Status changed from red to red - Elasticsearch is still initializing the kibana index.
  log   [02:57:52.123] [error][status][plugin:tilemap@5.2.0] Status changed from red to red - Elasticsearch is still initializing the kibana index.
  log   [02:57:52.124] [error][status][plugin:elasticsearch@5.2.0] Status changed from red to red - Elasticsearch is still initializing the kibana index.
  log   [03:00:45.436] [warning][process] UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 3): Error: reply interface called twice
    at emitPendingUnhandledRejections (internal/process/promises.js:57:27)
    at runMicrotasksCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:9)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:122:9)
 error  [03:00:45.465]  TypeError: Cannot read property 'toJSON' of undefined
    at withXpackInfo (/Users/yyq/Documents/es/kibana-5.2.0-darwin-x86_64/plugins/x-pack/plugins/xpack_main/server/lib/replace_injected_vars.js:5:32)
    at replaceInjectedVars$ (/Users/yyq/Documents/es/kibana-5.2.0-darwin-x86_64/plugins/x-pack/plugins/xpack_main/server/lib/replace_injected_vars.js:10:12)
    at tryCatch (/Users/yyq/Documents/es/kibana-5.2.0-darwin-x86_64/node_modules/regenerator/runtime.js:61:40)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (/Users/yyq/Documents/es/kibana-5.2.0-darwin-x86_64/node_modules/regenerator/runtime.js:328:22)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (/Users/yyq/Documents/es/kibana-5.2.0-darwin-x86_64/node_modules/regenerator/runtime.js:94:21)
    at invoke (/Users/yyq/Documents/es/kibana-5.2.0-darwin-x86_64/node_modules/regenerator/runtime.js:136:37)
    at callInvokeWithMethodAndArg (/Users/yyq/Documents/es/kibana-5.2.0-darwin-x86_64/node_modules/regenerator/runtime.js:172:16)
    at previousPromise (/Users/yyq/Documents/es/kibana-5.2.0-darwin-x86_64/node_modules/regenerator/runtime.js:194:19)
    at AsyncIterator.enqueue (/Users/yyq/Documents/es/kibana-5.2.0-darwin-x86_64/node_modules/regenerator/runtime.js:193:13)
    at AsyncIterator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (/Users/yyq/Documents/es/kibana-5.2.0-darwin-x86_64/node_modules/regenerator/runtime.js:94:21)
    at Object.runtime.async (/Users/yyq/Documents/es/kibana-5.2.0-darwin-x86_64/node_modules/regenerator/runtime.js:215:14)
    at replaceInjectedVars (/Users/yyq/Documents/es/kibana-5.2.0-darwin-x86_64/plugins/x-pack/plugins/xpack_main/server/lib/replace_injected_vars.js:3:22)
    at /Users/yyq/Documents/es/kibana-5.2.0-darwin-x86_64/src/ui/index.js:67:22
    at undefined.next (native)
    at step (/Users/yyq/Documents/es/kibana-5.2.0-darwin-x86_64/src/ui/index.js:9:273)
    at /Users/yyq/Documents/es/kibana-5.2.0-darwin-x86_64/src/ui/index.js:9:443
    at /Users/yyq/Documents/es/kibana-5.2.0-darwin-x86_64/src/ui/index.js:9:99
    at tryCatcher (/Users/yyq/Documents/es/kibana-5.2.0-darwin-x86_64/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/util.js:26:23)
    at ReductionPromiseArray._promiseFulfilled (/Users/yyq/Documents/es/kibana-5.2.0-darwin-x86_64/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/reduce.js:109:18)
    at ReductionPromiseArray.init (/Users/yyq/Documents/es/kibana-5.2.0-darwin-x86_64/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promise_array.js:92:18)
    at ReductionPromiseArray.init (/Users/yyq/Documents/es/kibana-5.2.0-darwin-x86_64/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/reduce.js:42:10)
    at Async._drainQueue (/Users/yyq/Documents/es/kibana-5.2.0-darwin-x86_64/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/async.js:128:12)
    at Async._drainQueues (/Users/yyq/Documents/es/kibana-5.2.0-darwin-x86_64/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/async.js:133:10)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (/Users/yyq/Documents/es/kibana-5.2.0-darwin-x86_64/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/async.js:15:14)

-------------------------------------
deMacBook-Pro:elasticsearch-head-master yyq$ grunt server
Running "connect:server" (connect) task
Waiting forever...
Started connect web server on http://localhost:9100
```

Comment: Try deleting your data directory (if loosing your old data is not an issue)

Comment: @RajindRuparathna After deleted my data directory, and restarting elasticsearch, kibana, elastichead, error ocurred. For detail message, please refer to the above.